# Trying to filter () column of factors

Tags: r, filter, dplyr

I have a data frame, `brfss2013` with 330 variables and 491775 obs.

One variable is

```
brfss2013$sex
2 levels... Factor w/ 2 levels "Male","Female": 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 1 2 ...
```

All I want to do is filter all the Females into  a data frame called *females*.

I've tried:

```
females <- filter(brfss2013$sex, sex == 'Female')
```

> ```
> Error in UseMethod("filter_") : 
>   no applicable method for 'filter_' applied to an object of class "factor"
> ```

also

```
females <-  filter(as.character(brfss2013$sex == 'Female'))
```

> ```
> Error in UseMethod("filter_") : 
>   no applicable method for 'filter_' applied to an object of class "character"
> ```

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Try `brfss2013.new <- brfss2013[brfss2013$sex %in% "Female", ]`.

Comment: Look at the help for `dplyr::filter`: it's called on a data frame. You're calling it on a factor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue arises from the filter syntax. You supply a vector, `brfss2013$sex` as the first parameter to the filter function when it's looking for a dataframe, `brfss2013`. When corrected, the filter function can be used to return a dataframe containing only those rows where the sex variable equals Female:

```
library(dplyr)
females <- filter(brfss2013, sex == "Female")
```

Comment: Many thanks.  That fixed my issue.  I try not to post on here too much as I'm really still learning to code.  I deeply appreciate the patience and guidance.

Comment: @enjaku Glad I could help. One way of checking this is to use the base R `class()` function on the filter inputs. `class(brfss2013)` reveals that it is a dataframe table while `class(brfss2013$sex)` reveals that it is a factor vector. The documentation for filter indicates that the first parameter requires a table input.